# How can I do for send date to cursor?

Tags: java, android, date, android-cursor

I can't get my Date with my cursor, I test all possibilities but I can't find a solution.

I have all tried.
The problem is the 4 line where I want to get the `KEY_DATE_TREATMENT`

```
 public List<Treatment> getTreatmentsList(){
        List<Treatment> tList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor c = getTreatments();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                SimpleDateFormat dateFormatprev = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date d = new Date();
                try {
                    d = dateFormatprev.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT)));
                }
                catch (ParseException e){

                }

                Treatment data = new Treatment(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_TREATMENT)),
                        c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IDPARCEL_TREATMENT)),
                        c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IDTREATMENTPRODUCT_TREATMENT)),
                        c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IDWEATHER_TREATMENT)),
                        c.getString(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT)));

                tList.add(data);
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();

    }
```

The error that I have currently is :

> getString(int) in Cursor cannot be applied to Java.lang.String

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest **code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix by change :-

```
c.getString(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT)));
```

To :-

```
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT));
```

You trying to use [**`c.getString()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor#getString(int)), with a **String** arg, not an **int** arg as you putting `c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT))` as the arg. The arg return **String** (***data you want getting***) not **int**.

Link say :-

> **getString**
>
> ```
> public abstract String getString (int columnIndex)
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> ***columnIndex***     int: the zero-based index of the target column.

**`c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT)`** gets an **int**, the column offset of the column that is name with the value of **KEY_DATE_TREATMENT** and work in **`getString`** method (like other lines that use **`getInt`**).

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra unnecessary and wrong call to `getString()`:

```
c.getString(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT)))
```

change to this:

```
        Treatment data = new Treatment(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID_TREATMENT)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IDPARCEL_TREATMENT)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IDTREATMENTPRODUCT_TREATMENT)),
                c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_IDWEATHER_TREATMENT)),
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE_TREATMENT)));
```